# How to open a command prompt with the console log from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have node.js and I want to open a cmd file with the console log when I run "node namefile.js".
So when I run the js file with "node namefile.js" it opens a cmd with the message I wrote
example: console.log("Hello World!");
It will open a cmd with "Hello World!"

The js file needs to create the cmd or open a new cmd as i know. I don't want to make a .cmd or .bat file and script the js file to open it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec('start cmd.exe @cmd /k "echo Hello World!', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    if(stdout)
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```